# Select where value exists more than once

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a project and have run into a problem. I need to display countries where the spoken language is the same in ascending order by language. My problem is that it will only display one row. My code so far.

```
SELECT country, language, population, count(*)
FROM demographics
GROUP BY language ASC
having count(*) > 1;
```

I want to display only the countries that share a common language, so if i had United States, and England both having English, and Portugal, and Brazil having Portuguese, I want only those four rows to be displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the query you have and use is as a sub-query, and join the demographics table to it.  Like this:

```
SELECT  d.*

FROM    demographics as d

JOIN 
(
SELECT language
FROM demographics
GROUP BY language ASC
having count(*) > 1
) as dups ON d.language = dups.language

ORDER BY language, country;
```